# How to Edit Domain and Have Edit Show in Attributes Dropdown

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, domains

I have created a previous domain with the same user login in ArcGIS 10.3. I wanted to add a coded value to this domain and, have the new addition show up on the drop-down options in the attributes when I add a new feature. I am able to add it to the domain. The issue is the addition is not showing up in the attributes when the new feature is created.

I have tried just plain open the properties in the gdb and add the addition to the domain. I have tried to use the tool "Add Coded Value To Domain". The addition is not showing up in the attrubutes.  I have tried to convert the domain to a table and than table to domain, new domain name. This worked but, when I changed the field domain to this new domain, no drop-down is shown when editing this field for a new feature.

Comment: Have you tried taking the domain off the field, then adding it back?

Comment: Yes I have even tried to taking that domain off of every field that it was selected for, before I edited that domain.

Comment: How about taking the domain off all fields, recreating it and setting fields again? Or am I misunderstanding that you've already done that? Maybe compressing the database after deleting the domain and before adding it back would clean up stray references. Worth a try.

Comment: That worked. Thank you recurvata. So, this is what I did to make it work. Turn off domain in all fields, which I did before. Then use "Domain to Table", which I did before. Then delete the domain completely, which I did not do, to nervous to do so previously. Then used "Table to Domain", which I previously did. I did not have to compress the database to get the change in the domain to work. Thanks again.

Comment: plese post your anser as an aswer and mark it as the correct answer not in comments.

Comment: @BradNesom,  are you referring to me or or @ARyanEnviro?

Answer (score 2):

So, this is what I did to make it work. Turn off domain in all fields, which I did before. Then use "Domain to Table", which I did before. Then delete the domain completely, which I did not do, to nervous to do so previously. Then used "Table to Domain", which I previously did. I did not have to compress the database to get the change in the domain to work. Thanks again.